# Add child array to every item of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a parent array called `$list`, and when I `var_dump($list);` this is the result:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Title #1' (length=7)
  1 =>
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '10' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'Title x' (length=7)

  ...

  9 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Title y' (length=3)
```

As you see i have two keys `'id'` and `'title'`.

I want to add another multidimensional array as an third key named `'children'`

I am able to get data of `'children'` with my function named `GetChildrenById($id);`

But i don't know how to add this array as a third key and name the key  `'children'`

*

I tried to reach every children by foreach loop but i need result as a big array.

How to achieve this?

Comment: How are you getting the results in the first place? What was the problem with using the foreach?

Comment: getting results from database. there is no problem with foreach but I don't want to echo out the result. I still need result as an array so i can json_encode(): later an so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need that:

```
foreach ($list as &$v) {
    $v['children'] = GetChildrenById($v['id']);
}
```

The `&` before `$v` indicates that `$v` is a reference to a `$list` item and not a copy. Consequence, when you apply a change to `$v`, the `$list` item is modified.

But you can also use the array indexes like that:

```
foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
    $list[$k]['children'] = GetChildrenById($v['id']);
}
```